# How do you find patterns/combinations within a String in Python?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I'm looking to return all instances of the following in Python, but not sure how. As in, how can I search a String and print every time the following format is found:

```
<a href="[what I'm trying to return is here]" class="faux-block-link__overlay-link"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an *HTML parser*, like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Sample:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> s = '<a href="[what I\'m trying to return is here]" class="faux-block-link__overlay-link">link</a>'
>>> BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser").a["href"]
u"[what I'm trying to return is here]"
```

where `.a` is equivalent to `.find("a")`. Note that `BeautifulSoup` provides a convenient *dictionary-like access* to element attributes.

Comment: @martineau: Sorry about that, quite new here. Thanks for letting me know.